# Adding routes for URL Shortener using Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid, url-shortener

I'm creating a URL shortener using Pyramid. I store the short and long urls in the db. Now my problem is how to create dynamic links from the short url to the long one.
Both urls are properly constructed.

Do I use config.add_route? If so how do I do that? Is there a better way?
Can I do this?

```
config.add_route(short_url, long_url)
```

Answer (score 2):

You would configure a single route. The first argument is the name of the route, and the second is the pattern used to match the request.

```
config.add_route('short_url', '/{short_url}')
config.scan()
```

Then you would add a view that would process the request, grab the matchdict value for `short_url`, look up in your database, then return a redirect response.

```
@view_config(route_name='short_url')
def url_expander(request):
    short_url = request.matchdict['short_url']
    # verify short_url is a valid format you define before doing a db query
    # your db query code to find long_url
    # SELECT long_url FROM t WHERE short_url=short_url
    # handle case of no match in db
    return HTTPFound(location=long_url)
```

See examples in the docs https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html#routing-examples and https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/views.html#using-a-view-callable-to-do-an-http-redirect.